# sorting dataframe by column name keeping first 3 columns as it is

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-conditions

I have dataframe with columns as

```
[u'Instructor Name', u'Product Name', u'Product Url', u' 2016.12.03',
u' 2016.12.05', u' 2016.12.01', u' 2016.12.12', u' 2016.12.16', 
u'2016.12.15', u' 2016.12.13', u' 2016.12.10', u' 2016.12.06', 
u'2016.12.14',u'2016.12.08', u' 2016.12.07', u' 2016.12.18', 
u'2016.12.11', u' 2016.12.04', u'2016.12.09', u' 2016.12.02', u' 2016.12.17']
```

I want to sort the columns but only that are in 'Product Url'. I want output

```
[u'Instructor Name', u'Product Name', u'Product Url',
       u' 2016.12.01', u' 2016.12.02', u' 2016.12.03', u' 2016.12.04',
       u' 2016.12.05', u' 2016.12.06', u' 2016.12.07', u' 2016.12.08',
       u' 2016.12.09', u' 2016.12.10', u' 2016.12.11', u' 2016.12.12',
       u' 2016.12.13', u' 2016.12.14', u' 2016.12.15', u' 2016.12.16',
       u' 2016.12.17', u' 2016.12.18', u' 2016.12.19']
```

How to do it.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Also, why would you have what appears to be dates as column names? And where did `hash` come from?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need cast `dates` columns [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_datetime.html), [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.sort_values.html) and if need `dates` use [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns[:3].tolist() + 
            (pd.to_datetime(df.columns[3:], format='%Y.%m.%d')).sort_values().date.tolist()
```

Sample:

```
cols = [u'Instructor Name', u'Product Name', u'Product Url', u' 2016.12.03', u' 2016.12.05', 
        u' 2016.12.01', u' 2016.12.12', u' 2016.12.16', u' 2016.12.15', u' 2016.12.13', 
        u' 2016.12.10', u' 2016.12.06', u'2016.12.14',u'2016.12.08', u' 2016.12.07', 
        u' 2016.12.18', u' 2016.12.11', u' 2016.12.04', u'2016.12.09',
 u' 2016.12.02', u' 2016.12.17']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols) 
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Instructor Name, Product Name, Product Url,  
          2016.12.03,  2016.12.05,  2016.12.01,  2016.12.12,  2016.12.16,  2016.12.15,  
          2016.12.13,  2016.12.10,  2016.12.06, 2016.12.14, 2016.12.08,  2016.12.07,  
          2016.12.18,  2016.12.11,  2016.12.04, 2016.12.09,  2016.12.02,  2016.12.17]

Index: []

[0 rows x 21 columns]

df.columns = df.columns[:3].tolist() + 
             (pd.to_datetime(df.columns[3:], format='%Y.%m.%d')).sort_values().date.tolist()

print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Instructor Name, Product Name, Product Url, 
          2016-12-01, 2016-12-02, 2016-12-03, 2016-12-04, 2016-12-05, 2016-12-06, 
          2016-12-07, 2016-12-08, 2016-12-09, 2016-12-10, 2016-12-11, 2016-12-12, 
          2016-12-13, 2016-12-14, 2016-12-15, 2016-12-16, 2016-12-17, 2016-12-18]
Index: []

[0 rows x 21 columns]
```

And if need same format add [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns[:3].tolist() + 
             (pd.to_datetime(df.columns[3:], format='%Y.%m.%d')).sort_values().strftime('%Y.%m.%d').tolist()

print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Instructor Name, Product Name, Product Url, 
          2016.12.01, 2016.12.02, 2016.12.03, 2016.12.04, 2016.12.05, 2016.12.06, 
          2016.12.07, 2016.12.08, 2016.12.09, 2016.12.10, 2016.12.11, 2016.12.12, 
          2016.12.13, 2016.12.14, 2016.12.15, 2016.12.16, 2016.12.17, 2016.12.18]
Index: []

[0 rows x 21 columns]
```